# Element-wise maximum with date values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime

I have a dataframe with date values and would like to manipulate them to 1 Jan or later. Since I need to do this element-wise, I use `np.maximum()`. The code below however gives

`TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'int'`.

What's the appropriate method to deal with this kind of data type?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': np.arange('1999-12', '2000-02', dtype='datetime64[D]')})
df['corrected_date'] = np.maximum(pd.to_datetime('20000101', format='%Y%m%d'), df['date'])
```

Comment: Use `np.datetime64('2000-01-01', dtype='datetime64[D]')` for comparison?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me working comparing with `Series`:

```
s  = pd.Series(pd.to_datetime('20000101', format='%Y%m%d'), index=df.index)
df['corrected_date'] = np.maximum(s, df['date'])
```

Or with `DatetimeIndex`:

```
i  = np.repeat(pd.to_datetime(['20000101'], format='%Y%m%d'), len(df))
df['corrected_date'] = np.maximum(i, df['date'])
```